# How to create IM chat client for skype?

Tags: blackberry

I am planing to create my own IM chat client for Blackberry and J2ME.Can anyone suggest me how to create our own chat client for blackberry. Is there is any api available to create such client application?

Answer (score 1):

Skype is closed source, but they do have a public API. I would check there.